# Iframe doesn't respond correctly to width

Tags: javascript, html, css, w3-css

I didn't have the best title here but here we go. So i am making a music website and i am trying to embed another page in my website into this website but i have nav bar.

I tried adding a bunch of different things in the css to make it not be so broken, if anyone has a fix or any way to make my question actually make sense feel free to edit or use the answer button. Thank you.

Sorry if it is confusing but, here is my code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #181414;
  color: white;
}

.embed {
  margin-left: 25%;
  border: 0px #ffffff none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: #3f3c3c;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #181414;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="Logo" onclick="location.href = 'https://www.ltunes.gq/'" ;><img src="https://ltunes.gq/assets/Logo.png" width="50" height="50">LTunes</div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="music">Music</a></li>
  <li><a class="active" href="radio">Radio</a></li>
  <li><a href="podcasts">Podcasts</a></li>
  <li><a href="lyrics">Lyric Search</a></li>
  <li><a href="jukebox">Jukebox</a></li>
  <li><a href="download">Download App</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="embed">
  <iframe class="embed" src="https://ltunes.gq/radio" name="Music" scrolling="yes" frameborder="1" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" height="100%" width="100%" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>


<script async src="https://arc.io/widget.min.js#eMnAzx6E"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:700" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.12/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-G0fIWCsCzJIMAVNQPfjH08cyYaUtMwjJwqiRKxxE/rx96Uroj1BtIQ6MLJuheaO9" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: no, i just wanted to make sure that i included all of the code in case somehow that could help.

Comment: Can you clarify what is the problem you're trying to solve?  " but i have nav bar" doesn't explain much. Are you trying to frame someone else's site but hide their site navigation?

Comment: I solved the problem it isn't worth fixing at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what i used to make it work:

```
     iframe {
  height: 100vh;  
  marginTop: 90px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 75%;
  margin-left:25%;
  border:0px #ffffff none; 
}
```

Comment: This is a working answer

Answer (score 0):

Onced faced the same issue, styled the iframe like so:

```
iframe {
  height: calc(91vh - 90px), // 90px - height of the containing app header
  marginTop: 90px, // 90px - height of the containing app header
  overflow: hidden,
  width: 100%,
}
```

Don't know if it would work but might worth giving it a shot

Comment: Kind of worked, the height is still not all the way down.

Comment: Found a fix, posting it now.